# Does Win10 IOT support Raspberry Pi3 touchscreen?

Tags: iot, windows-10-iot-core

I'm looking into a project involving Raspberry Pi 3 running Windows 10 IOT.
My question is whether or not this distribution of windows supports the Adafruit Touchscreen? (Pi Foundation Display 7)

https://www.adafruit.com/product/2718

I found this answer from a year ago, referencing the same question with Pi v2.
However I was unable to find an update on the current situation.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/48050b1d-5da1-488b-a888-144e159500c7/raspberry-pi-touch-display-and-windows-10?forum=WindowsIoT

So, can I use the Pi Foundation touchscreen with Win IOT?

I welcome you to share any experiences on the matter.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As @Naikrovek points out, it is supported and working. Feel free to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the Official Raspberry Pi Display works fine.